# Is there a memory leak, if yes, why?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Suppose I have a function that returns char*

```
char* GetName(int index);
```

And there is another function that has char* as an input parameter

```
void PrintName(const char* name);
```

so if I do

```
PrintName( GetName(10) );
```

is there a memory leak?
If yes, why? 
And is this the only way to handle this **without using std::string**:

```
char* name = GetName(10);
PrintName(name);
free(name);
```

Comment: We can't tell you if you don't show us the code.

Comment: Show the source code for GetName() and PrintName() and then we can provide an answer

Comment: Not just GetName() -- There could be allocs/deallocs in PrintName() too

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what does `GetName` return.

But as you have used `free( name )` I assume it returns dynamically allocated memory.

Then yes, there's a memory leak.

C++ does not have garbage collector. If you allocate memory, you need to free it.

Or use a smart pointer. Or a wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a memory leak as long as you free() the memory area returned by GetName(). But all depends on what's going on inside GetName();

Answer (score 1):

From what you have shared, there is nothing called memory leak, since you have not assigned any memory yet, which can leak. you just specified you might assign some memory and pass it around.

So, In short, It totally depends on what you write inside the functions `GetName` & `PrintName`

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, every `malloc` has to be matched with a `free`, every `new` with a `delete`, every `new[]` with a `delete[]`. You don't say what`GetName` does, but I'm assuming that it used `malloc`. In that case you have a memory leak since you don't call `free`.

The second piece of code is one way to avoid a memory leak, Another would be to call `free` in `PrintName` (probably not a good idea though since you wouldn't be able to call `PrintName` without dynamically allocated memory).

Of course it is precisely because this is difficult that you are recommended to use `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this alloc/dealloc manually asks for trouble, if you are not careful... So best you use something like std:string.

Having sayd that, if the char * is allocated inside GetName, then it needs to be deleted outside. You can think about this like ownership: GetName gives away the ownership by returning the char*, so its upto the one receiving the char* to continue handling it. You can either decide that PrintName takes ownership, then it has to delete it, or do it the way you have showed in your last example.

One easier approach would be to preallocate (preferrably on the stack):

```
char name[TheSizeYouNeed];
PrintName (GetName(10, name));
```

where GetName would do like that:

```
char *GetName (int len, char *buf) {
  strcpy (buf, "xxx");
  return buf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from what you wrote.
Basically, if you DON'T use the `malloc` keyword, then you don't have to call `free`. memory allocated on the stack (i.e, without using `malloc`) will be released when its scope is over.

But if you allocated inside `GetName` using `malloc`, the NOT calling `free` would cause a memory leak.

So it comes down to this:

- If you didn't use `malloc`, it won't leak.
- If you used `malloc` and didn't call free, it would leak.